# Get all first value of List<Object[]>

Tags: java

how can I retrieve only the pet types using lambda expression? I want a new list containing only "dog", "cat", etc,

I have list:

```
List<Object[]> list;
```

in this list I have structure:

```
list.get(0) returns ("dog", 11)  
list.get(1) returns ("cat", 22)  
etc.
```

how can I retrieve only the pet types using lambda expression? I want a new list containing only "dog", "cat", etc,

Comment: Why such a non-OOP structure? Isn't F# a better match?

Comment: What did you try so far? Have a look at the method `stream()` of your list and `filter()`, `map()`, `collect()` etc. on the streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way is the use of the stream api:

```
List firstElements = list.stream().map(o -> o[0]).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as using `map` and `collect`.

```
private void test(String[] args) {
    List<Animal> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Animal("dog",11));
    list.add(new Animal("cat",22));
    List<String> names = list.stream()
            // Animal -> animal.type.
            .map(a -> a.getType())
            // Collect into a list.
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(names);
}
```

I used `Animal` as:

```
class Animal {
    final String type;
    final int age;

    public Animal(String type, int age) {
        this.type = type;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Animal{" +
                "type='" + type + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}
```